# Creating new Gerrit project

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to create the first Gerrit project on a new server via SSH, but I can't get it to work.

I do:

```
ssh 192.168.0.106 -p 29418 -l fredrikpersson gerrit create-project --name fb-notifier.git
```

and get:

> Error when trying to create project: repository not found: Cannot
>   create repository fb-notifier

What's wrong?

Not sure it makes any difference, but I'm trying to do it through the Git Bash command window for Windows clients.

Comment: Do you really have a dash at the beginning of your project name?  That'll probably break all the command-line tools.

Comment: Ah sorry, I had copied the command line wrong to this question. The problem still persists though.

Comment: It's also not clear that fredrikpersson is a Gerrit Admin.  Can you verify that in your question?

Answer (score 2):

you can create project from Gerrit UI now with related authority. Admin->Projects->Create Project.

Comment: I am the admin but can't see the create project!

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your project with ".git".  Gerrit will add the .git suffix automatically:

```
ssh 192.168.0.106 -p 29418 -l fredrikpersson gerrit create-project --name fb-notifier
```